# What are the consequences of "$scalar = @array[n]"?

Tags: arrays, perl, slice

```
use warnings;
my @array = (0, 1);
my $scalar1 = $array[0];
my $scalar2 = @array[0];
if($scalar1 == $scalar2) {
    print "scalars are equal\n";
}
```

Here's the output when I run `/usr/bin/perl5.10.1 test.pl`:

```
Scalar value @array[0] better written as $array[0] at test.pl line 4.
scalars are equal
```

I'm concerned about that warning.

Comment: `eq` is an string operator. You should use `==` to compare scalars.

Comment: A string is a scalar.... Surely you mean "You should use `==` to compare numbers".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can look up all warning messages in [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html), which explains the consequences:

> (W syntax) You've used an array slice (indicated by @) to select a
>   single element of an array. Generally
>   it's better to ask for a scalar value
>   (indicated by $). The difference is
>   that $foo[&bar]  always behaves like a
>   scalar, both when assigning to it and
>   when evaluating its argument, while
>   @foo[&bar]  behaves like a list when
>   you assign to it, and provides a list
>   context to its subscript, which can do
>   weird things if you're expecting only
>   one subscript.
>
> On the other hand, if you were actually hoping to treat the array
>   element as a list, you need to look
>   into how references work, because Perl
>   will not magically convert between
>   scalars and lists for you. See
>   perlref.

Similarly, you can [use diagnostics;](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) to get this verbose explanation of the warning message.

A third way is to use the [splain](http://perldoc.perl.org/splain.html) utility.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to take an array slice of a single element:

```
@fruits[1]; # array slice of one element
```

but this usually means that you’ve made a mistake and *Perl will warn you* that what you really
should be writing is:

```
$fruits[1];
```

Comment: So, what are the consequences of going for the first method.

Comment: There are no consequences.  Perl is just trying to tell you that you will always get a scalar (a single element) so you might as well denote it like that - and this is because a single element  will always be treated like a one-element list in contexts that accept lists.

Answer (score 5):

There are no consequences for that usage. I think the purpose is to help you avoid the consequences when a warning can't be issued.

Slices on the LHS of "=" cause =" to be a list assignment operator.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { return 4; } my $x = $a[1] = f(); say $x'
4

$ perl -E'sub f { return 4; } my $x = @a[1] = f(); say $x'
1
```

Slices evaluate the index in list context.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { my @i = 3; @i } @a=qw( a b c d e f ); say @a[f()]'
d

$ perl -E'sub f { my @i = 3; @i } @a=qw( a b c d e f ); say $a[f()]'
b
```

Comment: @Eric Strom, The second one is actually extremely contrived. I couldn't think of a realistic situation.

Comment: How about someone thinking they can get something like *push* with *@rray[@rray] = 'new element'* instead of *$rray[@rray] = 'new element'*