# In Perl, why am I getting a warning when I use @_[0], @_[1], etc to access arguments to my subroutine?

Tags: perl, warnings

The below one the code.

```
sub max 
    {
        if (@_[0] > @_[1]) 
        {
            @_[0];
        }
        else
        {
            @_[1];
        }
    }
    print "biggest is ".&max(37,25);
```

When I ran it, I got the following warnings,

```
Scalar values @_[0] better written as $_[0] at file.pl line 3.
Scalar values @_[1] better written as $_[1] at file.pl line 3.
Scalar values @_[0] better written as $_[0] at file.pl line 5.
Scalar values @_[0] better written as $_[0] at file.pl line 9.
biggest is 37.
```

Although I got a correct output, but I wonder what could be the reason behind this warning, Since I think that using `@_` in a subroutine would be apropriate than `$_`.

Comment: I mean '@_' and '$_' not "@" and "$".

Comment: Don't add corrections in the comment field, use the `edit` button on your question to add the new information to your question instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the consequences of "$scalar = @array\[n\]"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298208/what-are-the-consequences-of-scalar-arrayn)

Comment: You're getting a warning for exactly the reason that Perl told you. Getting a single element from an array is better done using $, not @. The next time you get a warning from Perl that you don't understand, try adding `use diagnostics` to your code and see what that tells you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand it with this example:

```
@array = (1,2,3); #array is the name of the array and @ means that it's an array
print $array[1];  
#this will print element at index 1 and you're doing it in scalar context
```

Similarly,

```
@_ = (1,2,3); #_ is the name of the array
print $_[1]; 
#this will print element at index 1 of array _ and again you're doing it in scalar context
```

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that you are referring to your *single* array element by using an array slice instead of a scalar. Just like the error says. An array slice is a list of elements from an array, for example:

```
my @a = (0 .. 9);
print @a[0,3,4];    # prints 034
```

Conversely, when you refer to a single array element you use the scalar prefix `$`:

```
print $a[3];        # prints 3
```

So when you do

```
@_[0];
```

Perl is telling you that the proper way to refer to a *scalar* value is by not using an array slice, but rather to use the scalar notation:

```
$_[0];
```

That is all.

Comment: hm, not I try to imagine, how can I input into function specific parameters, so, `@_[0]` and `$_[0]` are not the same. @TLP, any ideas?

Comment: loldop: `$_[0]` has nothing to do with the variable `$_`. You read `_[0]` as "index 0 in the array called `_`, i.e. `@_`" and `$` as "return as scalar value".

Comment: @StefanMajewsky I know about difference between `$_` and `@_`. But I try to imagine in which situation in function `@_[0]` doesn't mean `$_[0]` (only if you use `scalar` function or other kind of operations/operators, which have different scalar/list/array behaviour)

Comment: @StefanMajewsky all good, I find good answer on queston above `What are the consequences of "$scalar = @array[n]"?` in comment to OP question

Comment: Perl does sometimes get it wrong though `perl -e'use warnings "syntax";@_[qw"0 1"]'`

Comment: @BradGilbert That's odd. It seems to be related to the type of delimiter used. `qw(...)` gives no such warning.

Comment: @Praveenkumar You know that you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to an array, instead of a scalar. `@_[0]` means `($_[0])`. But perl is kind of `clever` so it warns You that instead of an explicit single element list You should return a scalar. Here You should use `$_[0]`.

I suggest to use prototype, as now You could call `max (1, 2, 3)` and the result will be `2`, instead of `3`. So define as

```
sub max ($$) { $_[0] > $_[1]) ? $_[0] : $_[1] }
```

Or better, You can use for undefined number (>=2) of elements. Maybe pointless to call it with 0 or 1 items.

```
sub max (@) { 
    return undef if $#_<0; 
    my $s = shift; 
    for(@_) { $s = $_ if $_ > $s } $s 
}
```

Comment: Using Perl prototypes is usually... not a particularly good idea.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: Why not? It makes the definition more clear and does checks in compilation time.

Comment: "Perl 5's prototypes serve two purposes. First, they're hints to the parser to change the way it parses subroutines and their arguments. Second, they change the way Perl 5 handles arguments to those subroutines when it executes them. A common novice mistake is to assume that they serve the same language purpose as subroutine signatures in other languages. This is not true." - http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problem-with-prototypes.html

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: Generally I disagree with You. If You want to let the programmer to use the max for two scalars only (first case) then I would suggest to use the prototype. In second case I agree with You (more generix max()), because in that case it cannot be called with an array in the argument. I fixed that! Thanks for Your comment!

Comment: I guess a bare "return" is better than "return undef"

Comment: @cstamas: as you like. I even can imagine a rude `die` here.